# How to convert C# string expression into logic app expression for replace variable data

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have 2 variables and I want to remove one variable data from another .

```
var variable-A= "MYDATA1,MYDATA2,MYDATA88,MYDATA99,";
var variable-B= "MYDATA1,MYDATA2,";
```

I want to remove variable-B data from variable-A data.

Below C# code works fine I have converted same code into logic app expression but expression is having syntax error. How can I convert it correctly?

C# code -

```
var variable-A= "MYDATA1,MYDATA2,MYDATA88,MYDATA99,";
var variable-B= "MYDATA1,MYDATA2,";

var dummyString1 = variable-A.IndexOf(variable-B);
var dummyString2 = string.Concat(variable-A.Substring(0, dummyString1), variable-A.Substring(dummyString1 + variable-B.Length));
output is - `MYDATA88,MYDATA99,`
```

logic app expression -

```
concat(variables('variable-A').substring(0,variables('dummyString1')), variables('variable-A').substring(variables('dummyString1')+variables('variable-B').length))
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting? why not using `replace` ? `replace(variables('variable-A'), variables('variable-B'), '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax error I think it's caused by `Substring` function. The Substring expression should be like this `substring('<text>', <startIndex>, <length>)`, you could refer to this [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#substring).

And I agree with Thomas, the replace is easier to implement your requirement. You could have a try: `replace(variables('a'),variables('b'),'')` and this is [description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#replace) about replace.

[image]

Comment: its working for given string not working for-
string a = "USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,";
string b = "USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,T000,USRACL,USRACL,T000,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,T000,USRACL,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,T000,USRACL,T000,USRACL,USRACL,T000,T000,T000,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,T000,USRACL,USRACL,USRACL,T000,USRACL,T000,USRACL,T000,USRACL,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,T000,T000,USRACL,T000,T000,";

Comment: It fails cause it replace the whole string b (not every short string in b)  and string a doesn't contain b.

Comment: yea any suggestions to solve this ? it will be great help

Comment: or anything i can check while adding ... i'm using append string action is there any way to check if it is already present dont add

Comment: When you are trying to append the string you could use `contains(variables('value2'),variables('value1'))` to judge if the `value2` contains `value1`, if true then don't append.